# LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared. zed-csp

Tags: errors, packages, scientific-notation

I am writing my current journal paper using [Software: Practice and Experience Template](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/1097024x/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm). I need to use some **Z** notations. Therefore, I am using **zed-csp** package

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{zed-csp}
```

However, I am getting following errors -

- LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.
- LaTeX Error: Unknown symbol font `AMSb'.
- LaTeX Error: Command `\ulcorner' already defined.
- LaTeX Error: Command `\llcorner' already defined.
- and too many

Comment: most of the Z notations are in unicode and should be covered by the stix fonts that presumably the STIX1COL option loads, so it may be that you don't need the additional z-specific fonts,

Comment: if I don't use zed-csp packages, then it breaks formal schemas.

Comment: sure but you should be able to avoid loading more fonts, the zed-csp package detects lucida bright and if so uses the existing fonts rather than defining more, it could do the same for stix

Comment: how  to avoid loading more fonts? I did not get you

Comment: I think @DavidCarlisle is suggesting something which could be done in the `zed-csp` package rather than at the document level?